# Running NGINX and php-fpm Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, minikube

I have tried to deploy PHP-FPM with Kubernetes a few times using Mac M2 and running minikube on it in docker, however I still have not suceeded. When I try to reach NGINX NodePort it is only loading, however all the pods are running successfully.

I'm using the following HELM chart for nginx

```
helm install  my-release oci://registry-1.docker.io/bitnamicharts/nginx --values nginx-values.yaml
```

With the following *nginx-values.yaml*

```
service:
  type: NodePort

extraVolumes:
  - name: contents
    configMap:
      name: index
      items:
        - key: index.php
          path: index.php

  - name: nginx-config
    configMap:
      name: nginx
      

extraVolumeMounts:
  - name: nginx-config
    mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    subPath: nginx.conf
  - mountPath: /var/www/html/
    name: contents
```

Here is index Config Map file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo '<h1>Hello World</h1>'; ?>
        <?php phpinfo(); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is nginx Config Map file:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  access_log off;
  root /var/www/html;
  index index.php;
  server_name example.com;
  server_tokens off;
  location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }
  # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on wordpress:9000
  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      
    # Change The Service Name
    fastcgi_pass phpfpm:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}
```

And deployment files for php-fpm:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: phpfpm
  labels:
    app: phpfpm
    layer: backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: phpfpm
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: phpfpm   
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: phpfpm
          image: arm64v8/php:fpm-alpine #php:fpm-alpine 
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9000
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/www/html/
              name: contents
      volumes:
        - name: contents
          configMap:
            name: index
            items:
              - key: index.php
                path: index.php

---
kind: Service 
apiVersion: v1 
metadata:
  name: phpfpm
  labels:
    app: phpfpm
    layer: backend   
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: phpfpm
  ports:
    - port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000
```

Comment: Since the issue is with reaching the NGINX Nodeport, can you provide the detailed Nodeport service YAML file which will be useful in debugging the issue.

Comment: When you use bitnami helm charts for nginx, the default service type is loadbalancer, you don't need to change it. Try the default and see the results. Hope it helps!